# Debian 9: Iptables for Samba and SMTP is nowt working

Tags: debian, iptables, smtp, samba

I am currently trying to open the iptables firewall for Samba, but the configurations which I found on different portal are not working. Without firewall everything is working properly. With the firewall enabled I can not see any errors in the logs except in the nmbd.log.

```
[2017/07/24 15:07:47.107717,  0] ../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:873(send_udp)
  Packet send failed to 192.168.0.46(137) ERRNO=Operation not permitted
[2017/07/24 15:07:47.107808,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_packets.c:1026(reply_netbios_packet)
  reply_netbios_packet: send_packet to IP 192.168.0.46 port 137 failed
[2017/07/24 15:10:30.841301,  0] ../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:873(send_udp)
  Packet send failed to 192.168.0.255(137) ERRNO=Operation not permitted
[2017/07/24 15:10:30.841395,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_packets.c:179(send_netbios_packet)
  send_netbios_packet: send_packet() to IP 192.168.0.255 port 137 failed
[2017/07/24 15:10:30.841421,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_namequery.c:245(query_name)
  query_name: Failed to send packet trying to query name WORKGROUP<1d>
[2017/07/24 15:12:34.203550,  0] ../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:873(send_udp)
  Packet send failed to 192.168.0.255(138) ERRNO=Operation not permitted
[2017/07/24 15:12:34.203669,  0] ../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:873(send_udp)
  Packet send failed to 192.168.0.255(138) ERRNO=Operation not permitted
```

All Ports which are needed for samba are listening.

```
xyz@nuc:~# netstat -tulpn | egrep "samba|smbd|nmbd|winbind"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      517/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      517/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      517/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      517/smbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.255:137       0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.2:137         0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.255:137       0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.249:137       0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.255:138       0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.2:138         0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.255:138       0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.0.249:138       0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           576/nmbd
```

And the iptables configuration by now:

```
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT  DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT  DROP
iptables -P FORWARD  DROP

#Allow traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT


#dhcp
iptables -I INPUT -i enp0s25 -p udp --dport 67:68 --sport 67:68 -j ACCEPT

#Incoming ssh connection (server)
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s25 -p tcp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s25 -p tcp --sport 2222 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Outgoing ssh connection (client)
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s25 -p tcp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s25 -p tcp --sport 2222 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

##PING INCOMING ICMP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


##SMTP##
#iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT



##SMB

iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s25  -p udp --dport 137:138 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s25  -p udp --sport 137:138 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp0s25  -p tcp --dport 139 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s25  -p tcp --sport 139 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp0s25  -p udp --sport 445 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT




#iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT

#iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT


#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 139,445 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dport 137,138 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 139,445 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m multiport --dport 137,138 -j ACCEPT

#iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT



#Allow apt-get requests (HTTP)
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 --sport 32768:61000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 --dport 32768:61000 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
```

Can somebody give me a hint, how I can set up it the iptables for SMTP and samba correctly?

Best regards

Kaffi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line shown in the error log means the machine could NOT send UDP packet destined to port 137 (dropped by firewall). So, you need to add an ACCEPT rule for UDP to allow this port.

```
[2017/07/24 15:07:47.107717,  0] ../source3/libsmb/nmblib.c:873(send_udp)
  Packet send failed to 192.168.0.46(137) ERRNO=Operation not permitted
```

Similarly, you have an error for UDP port 138. These are NetBios ports. Add rules like these:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
```